# test cases got skipped in angular2

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-testing

I have written some  test cases ,when i try to run ng test only one test cases is being executed and the rest skipped

// my test.ts file

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

// Unfortunately there's no typing for the `__karma__` variable. Just declare it as any.
declare var __karma__: any;
declare var require: any;

// Prevent Karma from running prematurely.
__karma__.loaded = function () { };

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
// Finally, start Karma to run the tests.
__karma__.start();
```

// my karma.conf file

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul']
              : ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I could not understand where am doing wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add your testcase that isn't skipped? Sound like a use of `fit()` or `fdescribe()` to me.

Comment: yes, the file which which got executed has fit(),which means it test only that code ?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was exactly what I thought:

You used a `fit()` that forces karma to only execute this testcase.

More information here: https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/focused_specs.html